# How to filter genes in matrix based on quantile cutoff?

Tags: r, subset, bioinformatics, bioconductor, quantile

This is a matrix with some example data:

```
                  S1        S2       S3
ARHGEF10L       11.1818   11.0186  11.243
HIF3A            5.2482   5.3847   4.0013
RNF17            4.1956      0        0
RNF10            11.504   11.669.  12.0791
RNF11            9.5995   11.398    9.8248
RNF13            9.6257  10.8249    10.5608
GTF2IP1         11.8053  11.5487    12.1228
REM1             5.6835   3.5408    3.5582
MTVR2               0     1.4714      0
RTN4RL2          8.7486   7.9144    7.9795
C16orf13        11.8009   9.7438    8.9612
C16orf11            0        0         0
FGFR1OP2          7.679   8.7514    8.2857
TSKS             2.3036    2.8491   0.4699
```

I have a matrix "h" with 10,000 genes as rownames and 100 samples as columns. I need to select top 20% highly variable genes for clustering. But I'm not sure about what I gave is right or not.

So, for this filtering I have used [genefilter R package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/genefilter.html).

```
varFilter(h, var.func=IQR, var.cutoff=0.8, filterByQuantile=TRUE)
```

Do you think the command which I gave is right to get top 20% highly variable genes? And can anyone please tell me how this method works in a statistical way?

Comment: I would do this by converting your `matrix` into a `data.frame`. Is that something that's an option for you or would you like to stay within the `bioconductor` package framework? As for the underlying stats, I think that is one for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ok. Should I remove this question here and post in cross validated or just posting this link in cross validated is fine?

Comment: The question is fine here as it is I think, but if you'd like a detailed answer on the last part ("can anyone please tell me how this method works in a statistical way?") I'd post a separate one on Cross Validated for that.

Comment: Ok. And do you think this is right? for electing top 20% genes? vars <- apply(h, 1, sd);
h[vars > quantile(vars, 0.8), ]

Comment: Yes, I think @Jarko Dubbeldam's answer looks great and hits the nail on the head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used this package myself, but the helpfile of the function you're using makes the following remark:

> IQR is a reasonable variance-filter choice when the dataset is split
>   into two roughly equal and relatively homogeneous phenotype groups. If
>   your dataset has important groups smaller than 25% of the overall
>   sample size, or if you are interested in unusual individual-level
>   patterns, then IQR may not be sensitive enough for your needs. In such
>   cases, you should consider using less robust and more sensitive
>   measures of variance (the simplest of which would be sd).

Since your data has a bunch of small groups, it might be wise to follow this advice to change your `var.func` to `var.func = sd`.

`sd` computes the [standard deviation](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7v57y5YXVAhVJJlAKHd0uC6gQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FStandard_deviation&usg=AFQjCNF_tRY2X5GICM01Y4JjDxxMsPHMXg), which should be easy to understand.

**However**, this function expects its data in the form of an `expressionSet` object. The error message you got (`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'exprs' for signature '"matrix"'`) implies that you don't have that, but just a plain matrix instead.

I don't know how to create an `expressionSet`, but I think that doing that is overly complicated anyways. So I would suggest going with the code that you posted in the comments:

```
vars <- apply(h, 1, sd)
h[vars > quantile(vars, 0.8), ]
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to apply this to get top 20% genes?

Comment: `varFilter(h, var.func=sd, var.cutoff=0.8, filterByQuantile=TRUE)` should work.

Comment: Ok. but do you think with cutoff 0.8 the genes selected are top 20%? I know that it gives 20% genes from all the available genes, but not sure whether they are top 20% or not

Comment: Do you think this gives top 20%? I guess I'm right this time.                      vars <- apply(h, 1, sd);
h[vars > quantile(vars, 0.8), ]

Comment: Nope the one which you gave doesn't work and gives an error

Comment: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'exprs' for signature '"matrix"'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149092/discussion-between-raju-and-jarko-dubbeldam).